# Best Way to set min/max values in Django Model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to get a field called WipID in my model to have the following:
- Primary Key
- and to have numbers between 000000001 and 999999999

Basically I want the field to always have 9 numbers. I don't care about auto-increment or not.

I've tried a number variations, but right now I have this:

```
WipID = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(000000001), MaxValueValidator(999999999)])
```

I've tried `BigIntegerField` and `PositiveIntegerfield` and those haven't worked either.

What's the best way to accomplish this? Any help is greatly appreciated on this.

Comment: 000000001 isn't a number, it's a string. The number is just 1.

Comment: What's the point in saving "00000001" to the database? Just use 1 - 999999999 using what you have now (MinValueValidator(1) is correct way of doing it) and if you want to display it differently, write a custom `@property` on your model to display the field as string with prepending the 0s.

Comment: The information that we are using this for requires 9 digits ID's. So if I have something with an ID number of 1 in the database, but I display it as 000000001, nobody is going to know to search for just "1". Is my thinking right on this or no?